# Using PDO with 2 databases Intermittent error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, pdo, shared-hosting

Most of the time it works fine. Sometimes I refresh the screen once and it works and sometime I have to wait a few minutes. I have also gotten up and tried it on a different pc and it appears that if it is not working on one computer it is not working any where.

The program opens the databases in the same order each time and the error has occurred on both the first and the second database.

I have not seen a pattern.

I am using godaddy.com shared hosting.

PHP Version 5.2.17

PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version    5.0.77

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're connecting via TCP sockets, this could be due to an intermittent DNS lookup failure. e.g. your connection string uses 'mysql.example.com:3306', and whatever DNS server(s) your host is configured to use fails for whatever reason.